# Optimization - Issue with optimizing the surface area of a blimp [Pre-Caclulus]

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

I am having issues optimizing a blimp's surface area. Here is the question:

> Engineers are working on an airship to publicize various events. The front and back of the blimp are semi-ellipsoids with a cylinder between the two. Given that the major axis of the semi-ellipsoid is two times the length of the minor axis, and the volume of the blimp is 250,000 cubic feet, what is the minimum surface area of the blimp?

For a visual model →
[Visual Model & Formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVZfc.jpg)

Unfortunately, when optimizing the blimp's surface area, I somehow got a negative length. I graphed the surface area equation along with its derivative (f'(x)) in Desmos which also returned the same minimum value.

Please view the work for optimization first → [Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFdNm.png) [Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arkVJ.png)

This is the Desmos graph → [Desmos Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FUJm.jpg)

I also verified with my teacher that the minimum I got was correct. She was unsure about what went wrong with the question. My best guess is that there was a problem with the wording of the actual problem (perhaps the parameters aren't possible).

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I think you can save quite a lot of ink in the calculations by observing that $(2r^2)^{1.6075}+(r^2)^{1.6075}+(2r^2)^{1.6075}=(2(2^{1.6075})+1)r^{2\cdot{1.6075}}$ (for positive $r$) and hence $$\left(\frac{(2r^2)^{1.6075}+(r^2)^{1.6075}+(2r^2)^{1.6075}}3\right)^{1/1.6075}=1.70818 r^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

When minimizing any expression, it is *on you* to ensure that the domain constraints (in this case, $r\ge0$ and $l\ge0$) are satisfied. If you don't, the minimum you get may be nonsense even if you take all the derivatives correctly.

In this case, you have solved for $l$ and gotten $l = \frac{250000 - \frac83 \pi r^3}{\pi r^2}$. But the constraint $l\ge 0$ must hold, so we require that $250000 - \frac83 \pi r^3 \ge 0$. This means $r \le 25 (\frac6\pi)^{1/3}$, an upper bound of about $31.0175$.

When you set $\frac{d(SA)}{dr} = 0$ and solved for $r$, you found the global minimum of your expression for surface area. (It could have been a maximum, or only a local minimum, or even just a critical point - but the graph shows it's a minimum, and I assume that this is why you wanted the graph.) However, that global minimum is outside the interval $[0,25 (\frac6\pi)^{1/3}]$, and so it does not solve the problem.

Instead, it's enough to observe that for all $r$ such that $0 \le r \le 25 (\frac6\pi)^{1/3}$, the derivative $\frac{d(SA)}{dr}$ is negative; we can obtain this algebraically or by looking at the graph. This means that as $r$ increases, the surface area decreases, and we minimize the surface area by increasing $r$ as high as it can go. But no higher than that!

Therefore the optimal solution is actually obtained by setting $r$ *equal* to $25 (\frac6\pi)^{1/3}$ (and $l=0$). For this value of $r$, the surface area is about $20651.8$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you got ≤25(6)1/3? Thank you.

Comment: Not much to it: $250000 - \frac83 \pi r^3 \ge 0 \iff \frac83 \pi r^3 \le 250000 \iff r^3 \le \frac{750000}{8\pi} \iff r \le (\frac{750000}{8\pi})^{1/3}$.